# Number of logins on Linux using Shell script and AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk

How can I get the number of logins of each day from the beginning of the **wtmp** file using AWK?
I thought about using an associative array but I don't know how to implement it in AWK..

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN{numberoflogins=0}
 #code goes here'
```

The output of the `last` command:

```
[fnorbert@localhost Documents]$ last
fnorbert tty2         /dev/tty2        Mon Apr 24 13:25   still logged in  
reboot   system boot  4.8.6-300.fc25.x Mon Apr 24 16:25   still running  
reboot   system boot  4.8.6-300.fc25.x Mon Apr 24 13:42   still running  
fnorbert tty2         /dev/tty2        Fri Apr 21 16:14 - 21:56  (05:42)  
reboot   system boot  4.8.6-300.fc25.x Fri Apr 21 19:13 - 21:56  (02:43)  
fnorbert tty2         /dev/tty2        Tue Apr  4 08:31 - 10:02  (01:30)  
reboot   system boot  4.8.6-300.fc25.x Tue Apr  4 10:30 - 10:02  (00:-27)
fnorbert tty2         /dev/tty2        Tue Apr  4 08:14 - 08:26  (00:11)
reboot   system boot  4.8.6-300.fc25.x Tue Apr  4 10:13 - 08:26  (-1:-47)
wtmp begins Mon Mar  6 09:39:43 2017
```

The shell script's output should be:

```
Apr 4: 4
Apr 21: 2
Apr 24: 3
```

, using associative array if it's possible

Comment: To make this question self-contained, you should post more information: what are the contents of `wtmp`? What's the path to its location?

Comment: You can start by showing us your input file

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear enough what I said. I meant the last line from the output of the **last** command, where says: "wtmp begins Mon Mar  6 09:39:43 2017". I don't know this file where can be found, just I heard about it and I thought it will be useful if I mention it.

Comment: You should show the example output of `last` then, and what the output of your script should be.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question

Comment: Please let us know [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, arrays can be indexed by strings or numbers, so you can use it like an associative array.

However, what you're asking will be hard to do with awk reliably because the delimiters are whitespace, therefore empty fields will throw off the columns, and if you use `FIELDWIDTHS` you'll also get thrown off by columns longer than their assigned width.

If all you're looking for is just the number of logins per day you might want to use a combination of sed and awk (and sort):

```
last | \
  sed -E 's/^.*(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([ 0-9]{2}).*$/\2 \3/p;d' | \
  awk '{arr[$0]++} END { for (a in arr) print a": " arr[a]}' | \
  sort -M
```

The `sed -E` uses extended regular expressions, and the pattern just prints the date of each line that is emitted by `last` (This matches on the day of week, but only prints the Month and Date)

We could have used `uniq -c` to get the counts, but using awk we can do an associative array as you hinted.

Finally using `sort -M` we're sorting on the abbreviated date formats like `Apr 24`, `Mar 16`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ***awk*** script(assuming that the month is the same, points to current month):

***myscript.awk:***

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
    a[NR]=$0;   # saving each line into an array indexed by line number
}
END {
    for (i=NR-1;i>1;i--) {  # iterating lines in reverse order(except the first/last line)
        if (match(a[i],/[A-Z][a-z]{2} ([A-Z][a-z]{2}) *([0-9]{1,2}) [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/, b)) 
            m=b[1];     # saving month name
            c[b[2]]++;  #  accumulating the number of occurrences
    } 
    for (i in c) print m,i": "c[i]
}
```

---

***Usage:***

```
last | awk -f myscript.awk
```

The output:

```
Apr 4: 4
Apr 21: 2
Apr 24: 3
```